# Isn't \csname foo\endcsname = \foo?

Tags: csname

On p. 40 of the TEXbook, it says that `\csname TeX\endcsname` is
essentially the same as `\TeX`.  But, if that is so, why isn't `\foo`
defined below?

```
% tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=tex)
**\def\csname foo\endcsname{bar}

*\message{\csname foo\endcsname}
bar
*\message{\foo}
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \message{\foo
                }
?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\def\csname foo\endcsname{bar}
```

redefines `\csname`, you wanted

```
\expandafter\def\csname foo\endcsname{bar}
```